# Examples of nCr (combinations) notation

Tags: notation, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

I understand what nCr is as far as what the formula is, but I ran across this notation and have no clue how I’m supposed to read this. Is it asking for 3 different combinations (*the sum* C *each letter individually*) or is it asking for something else?

$$\binom{i + j + k}{i, j, k}$$

Comment: $\binom{i + j + k}{i, j, k}$. \binom{i + j + k}{i, j, k}

Comment: I believe you're looking at a [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients)

Comment: Context matters.  Where did you "run across" this notation?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

The notation
$$\binom ab$$
is used to denote the number of ways to choose a subset of $b$ objects from $a$ distinguishable objects. It can also be thought of as the way to partition a set of $a$ objects into two buckets, the first of which must have $b$ objects and the second of which has $b-a$ objects. This can be seen from its evaluation
$$\binom ab=\frac{a!}{b!(a-b)!}.$$
What if you want to count the number of ways to partition a set of $a$ objects into more than $2$ buckets? Say we want a notation to partition a set of size $n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_m$ into $m$ buckets, the first of which is of size $n_1$, the second of which is of size $n_2$, et cetera. This can be represented by the fraction
$$\frac{(n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_m)!}{n_1!n_2!\cdots n_m!}.$$
When discussing such numbers, it can be useful to have some shorthand. So, this is often written
$$\binom{n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_m}{n_1,n_2,\dots,n_m}.$$
For example,
$$\binom8{2,2,4}=\frac{8!}{2!2!4!}=420.$$

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this is called a multinomial coefficient.